# Add event listener to a textbox initiated with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two textboxes with `start_date` and `end_date` respectively.

I am not able to `addEventListener` after it has been initiated with the datepicker else I am able to handle events on the textbox.
below is my js code.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
                    //$("#start_date").datepicker();
                    $("#end_date").datepicker();
                    /*$('.d_picker').keydown(function (){
                       return false; 
                    });*/
                    var startDate = document.getElementById('start_date');
                    startDate.addEventListener('change',function (){
                        /*startDateVal = document.getElementById('start_date').value;
                        $("#end_date").datepicker("option","minDate",startDateVal);*/
                        console.log('Element '+this.name+' clicked');
                    },true);

                    var endDate = document.getElementById('end_date');
                    endDate.addEventListener('change',function (){
                        console.log('Element '+this.name+' clicked');
                    },true);
                });
```

I get below as output in console:

> Element start_date clicked

but end_date event is never triggered on change

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>event listeners in javascript</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/third_party_libs/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Start Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" class="d_picker" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" class="d_picker" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="assets/third_party_libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/third_party_libs/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
                //$("#start_date").datepicker();
                $("#end_date").datepicker();
                /*$('.d_picker').keydown(function (){
                   return false; 
                });*/
                var startDate = document.getElementById('start_date');
                startDate.addEventListener('change',function (){
                    /*startDateVal = document.getElementById('start_date').value;
                    $("#end_date").datepicker("option","minDate",startDateVal);*/
                    console.log('Element '+this.name+'clicked');
                },true);

                var endDate = document.getElementById('end_date');
                endDate.addEventListener('change',function (){
                    console.log('Element '+this.name+'clicked');
                },true);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding an e.preventDefault() inside the endDate eventListener callback?

Comment: Could be because there is no `textinput` event

Comment: I suspect this library doesn't broadcast a `textinput` event.

Comment: i have updated my question...i was just checking out the `textinput` option...but it doesnt work on `click`,`change` or `select` either

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: updated my question with HTML

Comment: I would stick with one paradigm - if you're using jQuery already, add your event listener using `$('#end_date'').on('change', function(){});`

Comment: Your example seems to be working for me, the only thing changed in case of end_date is that datepicker is restricting user to enter only numeric field

Comment: yes get your intent but prefer to use javascript all the way here....
its just a `textbox` afterall with an `id`

Comment: @Deep
can you share your code?
i cant seem to get the result on console
have you changed something?

Comment: @coolstoner - sure I get that, but jQuery is Javascript and if you're already using jQuery UI then it would make it easier to test and track down bugs - have you looked into the jQuery UI datepicker API - I think you can do something like this `$('#end_date'').datepicker({ onSelect: function() {$(this).change();} });`

Comment: Just comment `$("#end_date").datepicker();` temporarily, and try to run your code again. You will see that there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @PiyushSonagara
yes i get that...there is nothing wrong in the code...its the mix and match thats not working....i am not able to `addEventListener` to a jquery datepicker

Comment: @coolstoner https://plnkr.co/edit/pEV5weIpL00OBMr6cI6m?p=preview

Comment: @Deep `alert` is called only for `start_date` when it is changed as in code and not for `end_date` after change of date in datepicker...
i would like to know why this is so?

Comment: @coolstoner Well the change event does work on datepickers. Try to enter some numeric value like `123` in the box and focus out from that input box. Observe your console, you will get a message.

Comment: @PiyushSonagara only for `start_date` and not for `end_date`

Comment: @PiyushSonagara i have not called `start_date` with datepicker only `end_date`..i observed this strange behaviour where i couldnt bind an event to a datepicker instance and so i removed the datepicker from `start_date` to check the same....hence `start_date` works fine as a `normal textbox`

Comment: @coolstoner Have a look at http://pastebin.com/rUdF1Y4y. I just used CDNs for jQuery scripts and CSS files. No changes have been made to your code. It works fine.

Comment: @PiyushSonagara i see it with my local files too now...so it is the `change` event is not registered with the `datepicker` but by manually entering numbers...
`select` doesnt work either but this is a move in the right direction...thanks for pointing out...

Comment: @coolstoner -- Datepicker restricts the characters you can type in the textbox. Refer to the datepicker's docs to get more details about it.

Comment: @PiyushSonagara i just figured it out myself and was to type it here...
only `/` and numerals allowed...so if i manually change the textbox with `/` or `[0-9]+` it shows the message in console

Answer (score 2):

If you *want* to use jQuery then this is the easiest solution -

```
 $("#end_date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      $(this).change();
    }
  });

  $('#end_date').on('change', function() {
    alert('Element ' + this.name + 'clicked');
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jGwZr88ZeHtKPkruAF8u?p=preview